# MQTT TLS on port 8883 for outside world and 1883 for client in other docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a docker-compose file where I have a MQTT container and a python app container. The MQTT container must be able to accept connections over tls and port 8883 from the outside world. Only a client located in the other python app container should be able to connect unencrypted over port 1883.

Encrypted connections work. The only thing I don't know is how to define port 1883 for my other app container.

If I use the IP address (in mosquitto.conf) of the app container I will have to change it manually whenever it changes the IP of the app container. Is it possible to use the container name?

How can I define this in mosquitto.conf?

```
listener 8883
listener 1883 <app container host> ?
```

i mean if docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: ...
    .
    .

  mqtt-xyz:
    build: ...
    .
    .
```

then mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 8883
listener 1883 app
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind both listeners to the default wildcard (0.0.0.0), and then only map the 8883 listener to the host in the compose file `ports` section.

You can then access the broker internally by the service name `mqtt-xyz` on port 1883

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But i have another issue with this setting. maybe you can take a look :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562097/mqtt-port-8883-and-1883-enable-at-the-same-time-dont-work

Answer (score 1):

To respond to your Question "can i use container NAME instead of IpAddress" yes you can but it's need to be in the same netework in your docker-compose file

and for "can i use multiple ports" according to Mosquitto documentation yes you can use multiple listener in config file

> mosquitto.conf

[Check the GitHub Doc for Mosquitto](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/4ac8c0bcc34c8640e8c6a931e8e63ea4f250c6c7/mosquitto.conf#L214)

I hope i helped you ,let me know if you need more help.