# MQTT port 8883 and 1883 enable at the same time dont work

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a docker-compose file where I have a MQTT container and a python app container. The MQTT container must be able to accept connections over tls and port 8883 from the outside world. Only a client located in the other python app container should be able to connect unencrypted over port 1883.

Certificates seems to be ok. if i only enable listener 8883 then communication works. Also if i only enable listener 1883 it works too. **Only if i use together i doesnt work.**

The issue is that when i put `listener 8883 0.0.0.0` and `listener 1883 0.0.0.0` in the config file then i cant connect at port 8883 with certs and neither at port 1883.

compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    .
    .
    networks:
    - frontend
    - mqtt
  app:
    . 
    .
    networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
    - mqtt
  mqtt-8vv30kj5g5u4:
    .
    .
    networks:
    - mqtt
networks:
  frontend:
    name: frontend-network
  backend:
    name: backend-network
  mqtt:
    name: mqtt-network
```

My mosquitto.conf file:

```
listener 8883 0.0.0.0
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
max_connections -1
protocol mqtt
certfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/server.key
crlfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/ca.crl
require_certificate true
cafile /mosquitto/config/certificates/ca.crt
allow_anonymous true
```

Connecting over port 8883 using tls i get the error `SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)` at client side. The mosquitto.log file in broker says:

```
1654783087: New connection from 172.28.0.2:57262 on port 8883.
1654783087: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
```

Connecting over port 1883 throws no error. But the mosquitto.log file says:

```
1654783976: New connection from 172.28.0.6:38193 on port 1883.
1654783976: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1404A42E:SSL routines:ST_ACCEPT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
1654783976: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

Can you maybe see an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order in the mosquitto.conf file is important.

With

```
listener 8883 0.0.0.0
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
max_connections -1
protocol mqtt
certfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/server.key
crlfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/ca.crl
require_certificate true
cafile /mosquitto/config/certificates/ca.crt
allow_anonymous true
```

You have defined `listener 8883 0.0.0.0` with the default settings (no ssl at all) and `listener 1883 0.0.0.0`  with all the SSL config that follows in the config file.

What you probably want is this:

```
per_listener_settings true

listener 1883 0.0.0.0
allow_anonymous true

listener 8883 0.0.0.0
max_connections -1
certfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/server.key
crlfile /mosquitto/config/certificates/ca.crl
require_certificate true
cafile /mosquitto/config/certificates/ca.crt
allow_anonymous false
```

This sets up SSL on port 8883 (and disables anonymous connections since you are requiring a client SSL cert) and allows anonymous access on port 1883

Comment: Thank you hardillb for your help!

Comment: Add an update: I'm using 2.0.18 on Win10. The line "per_listener_settings" needs to be changed to "per_listener_settings true".